To what extent is a person responsible for morally reprehensible beliefs if he was raised to believe them?
Somehow this feels like a relevant question in light of the current turmoil. There are radicalized people who are radicalized from childhood and have no regard for anything other than belief or party doctrine. In other words, if two terrorists give birth to a boy who grows up in a terrorist family to become a terrorist. Is he wrong?
How do we approach this question from a philosophical perspective? The utilitarian vs categorical imperative moral dichotomy or what?

It seems that the title and the body of your question do not match: You may ask either about Stockholm syndrome or about being educated by parents who are terrorists.

Are you saying that the boy grwing up in a "radicalized" environment will become radicalized? Maybe: the environment is crucial for the "education" of children. Are you asking if he will be responsible for its own future acts, if any? Yes, of course: free will.

The only fair way, that I can find, is accepting that free will doesn't exist, and that neither the parent-terrorists, or the child-terrorist can know or do any better unless they are met with an input of sufficient magnitude so that they could potentially change their perspective. So it is the moral responsibility of society as a whole to facilitate such an input.

Apparently it is a simple question, but IMO it is quite slippery... I'm responsible for my belief? Yes, they are mine... But what does it mean to be responsible for a belief? I'm responsible for my acts, for the act of "my" dog", but what about my belief in astrology? and my belief in (say) Liverpool Football Club?

@MauroALLEGRANZA How do you differentiate acts and beliefs? You are punished if you act in discord with societal expectations, but there is no necessary relationship with responsibility there. And if someone believes they can fly, are they responsible for the act of jumping, if they are not responsible for the belief?

The question should decide by which moral framework this should be decided. Each has a different answer. The meta decision of which framework to pick is not a moral one, that would lead to infinite regress.

@Sammich -"How do you differentiate acts and beliefs?" Do you think that there is no difference? If I'm believing in astrology, there is now law (I hope :-) ) that forbid me to do so. If I'm robbing a bank I'm committing a crime.

Forget about morals, look at what works: a society of terrorists will destroy itself, and terrorists will be stopped by a different society. Forget about responsibility and just ask this person, "Are you going to learn to do what works, or be stupid your whole (short) life?" It's called Engineering: do things that work.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I think there is a difference, in that a belief facilitates any act, and since you claim that responsibility of your beliefs are not the same as the act, the way in which you differentiate seems actual in the discussion. You act on beliefs, rarely vice versa.

@tkruse Not a moral one, yes. But is it a possible one?

There's polysemy around 'terrorist'.  Before we can answer the question you must say which leg of the polysemy you choose for your semantics.

I suspect that you would find, for many individuals you might label "terrorists", that they are asking the exact same question about you.  IMHO much of this boils down to the degree that we can accept moral relativism.  Is it possible in the true moral axioms that, from your POV, you are good and they are evil and from their POV you are evil and they are good?

Pls make that an answer @Him

Relevant smbc comic

One way to answer "Is he wrong?" in various shades of "no" is through moral relativism.
I suspect that you would find, for many individuals you might label "terrorists", that they are asking the exact same question about you. Is it possible in the true moral axioms that, from your POV, you are good and they are evil and from their POV you are evil and they are good?
Note that one need not go full nihilist to end up with unresolvable conflict in moral situations.  For example, consider if the true moral axioms involve a "local morality".  In "local morality", your primary duty is first toward friends and family, then community, then the rest of humanity.  The "local morality" could be framed in consequentialist or deontological terms, we'll just leave that an open question.  Now, while the world economy isn't a zero sum game, resources are yet finite (one zero-sum-ish aspect is control of land).  This sets up a contention: Either you, your family and your community have the land or "they" do.  This description would be accurate from the POV of both sides of a land-conflict.  So, in a "local morality", it could be the case that both sides are "right" to fight one another for control of the land.
I bring up "local morality" specifically because this is often taught to people when growing up.  "Family comes first" is a very common moral opinion in humans.  If "family first" is actually not compatible with the true moral axioms, then I think that the "terrorists" have much company in being in the wrong.
I suspect that "local morality" is not the only relativistic system that creates this sort of moral conflict where simple right v wrong dichotomy is too naive to address the situation.  However, I think that some degree of moral relativism is probably necessary to erase the conflict: if a person is harming you and you are harming them in return, then you are unlikely to both be in the right in a moral absolutist framework, utilitarian or otherwise.

Tnx for answering, though I don't agree the last sentence — did Christ prove the Sanhedrin or the Romans wrong by peacefully ascending the cross? This may be an extreme asymptomatic example but there are other more day to day similar ones, eg Gandhi. Also Sir Thomas More

@Rushi agreed.  I wanted to phrase as "if you are harming a person and they are harming you", but this seemed to go beyond the OP's question.  Will update.

To start with the title of your question, "To what extent is a person responsible for morally reprehensible beliefs if he was raised to believe them?", the answer is zero percent responsible. Raising a person to a certain type of belief is already an irresponsible act, almost like a crime. This isn’t just about a particular group; it applies to every society, every religion, and every culture. The very foundation of these structures relies on belief, which is completely based on "not knowing." Anything you do not know you believe. The more you believe, the more you suppress doubt and stop inquiry—this is one of the most effective ways to stifle human intelligence. Everything we have as human beings, in terms of material, intellectual, and spiritual growth, is based on doubt and inquiry.
All our conflicts, wars, violence, and divisions come from one belief system. Beliefs that seem valid in one part of the world look ridiculous in another, leading to unavoidable conflict. This isn’t the question of right or wrong, moral or immoral; it’s about belief itself. In this scenario, any act cannot be considered responsible, because responsibility comes with awareness. Only an individual, not a believer, can be truly aware, because the moment you act based on belief, you are already in corruption.
That’s why every human being must act responsibly for themselves only—not for some belief or prejudice, regardless of their upbringing. They must act freely, with a sense of complete independence as individuals, not as personalities created by society, because society tries to create personalities out of individuals for its own purposes.

What you're saying amounts to: For every criminal convicted hang his parents Being slightly sardonic here... but only slightly. The thing is I see where you're coming from and I agree with the drift but how do you deal with the infinite regress — we must punish all the way back to Adam and Eve?

@Rushi "I am not asking for punishment for any past acts. For whatever reason and circumstance a person has developed into who they are, that is already over, for both good and bad. However, as grown individuals, any further actions should not continue solely based on their upbringing in the name of responsibility; it must be a question of choice. We are part of evolution in all dimensions, engaging intellect and consciousness; that is why it is our responsibility to ask questions and take a different path if needed."

Yes that's why I said I somewhat agree. The thing is there's a difference between private morals/ethics and public jurisprudence. In the case of the former your outlook works but in the case of the latter it doesn't — a judge may know in his heart that there are no heinous criminals, that everyone is an unwitting product of circumstance. But still he must do his job, and hand out sentences. That doesn't work without assuming some responsibility somewhere. [As a teacher I've handed out dozens of F grades. At some level I know each F means I failed. But still I must give them]

From a utilitarian perspective, behaviors matter, not beliefs, which can only be deemed immoral if they compel one to behave in a manner that creates unecessary suffering.
IOW, for a utilitarian there can be no such thing as a "morally reprehensible belief."
If I was raised to believe that, say, all Israelis are liars and that all Palestinians are terrorists, but I never act upon these beliefs nor say anything about them, then my beliefs have no consequences and hence are not inherently immoral from a utilitarian POV. However, I would become guilty of propagating racism and complicit to mass murder if I ever voiced those opinions.


There are radicalized people who are radicalized from childhood and have no regard for anything other than belief or party doctrine. In other words, if two terrorists give birth to a boy who grows up in a terrorist family to become a terrorist. Is he wrong?

I believe this statement seriously trivializes the actual problems and suggests a caricature of (1) how adolescents and adults may become politically radicalized, (2) what kind of psychological trauma (childhood abuse, growing up in atrociously bad circumstances such as in a war zone) may lead to stunted moral development or contribute to narcisistic traits or cynical lack of empathy with "others".
A moral attitude towards terrorists -- as persons -- is almost by definition a moralistic futile attitude. It aggravates existing polarization (shunning of others, avoidance of dialogue, refusal to consider simple facts) and can only result in less mutual understanding. It's futile since it doesn't help in any way to get at the actual causes of terrorism or to make the world safer for everyone by removing those causes. It's moralistic, since it's mostly a form of self-aggrandizement. Nobody -- at any side -- believes "terrorism" is good. The question is why do some people feel compelled to act out in those ways? What were the conditions that drove them to those heinous acts? Perhaps we should consider those conditions too, and see those as the actual "terrorism" rather than the reaction to those conditions. What is needed to eliminate those conditions? -- rather than eliminate the people growing up in those conditions or the people who, unwittingly or not, may be contributing to those conditions.
We are all in this together. Nobody has clean hands.

The human mind is designed to interpret everything it experiences, turning raw sensory input into concepts and ideas. This interpretation process is essential for us to understand our surroundings and navigate life. From this perspective, duality, our tendency to split things into pairs like "good" and "bad," "right" and "wrong" arises naturally. It’s the result of the brain’s need to categorize and make sense of the world.
However, concepts like "right" and "wrong" don’t exist in an absolute, literal sense. They are interpretations, ways to describe experiences, rather than universal truths. Instead of being fundamental qualities of life, they reflect how we label actions or events based on the impact they have on us and others. For instance, actions we call "bad" or "destructive" are usually those associated with pain, harm, or loss. But pain and loss, as parts of life, aren’t inherently "wrong", They’re just aspects of existence that our minds interpret as wrong due to the discomfort or harm they cause.
In this way, life itself is more like a phenomenon, a flow of events and actions that simply are. Each part of life, from joy to suffering, creation to destruction can be seen as just another descriptive part of existence, without needing a moral label. When we label things as "bad" or "good," we’re interpreting them through our human perspective, not defining absolute qualities.
So, when someone holds beliefs that we might see as harmful or "morally wrong," it’s not that they are inherently wrong as a person. Their beliefs are a result of how they’ve interpreted life, shaped by their upbringing and environment. Just as life isn’t truly "good" or "bad," their beliefs are neither entirely right nor wrong, they’re just part of how they’ve come to see the world. However, because every action based on these beliefs has real effects, they are responsible for the consequences of their beliefs and actions.
Responsibility here isn’t about blame, it’s about the awareness that every action has a cause and effect. As people grow and experience more, they have the opportunity to question and reinterpret their beliefs. They might come to see that some interpretations, like beliefs that harm others, don’t serve them or the world well. This reinterpretation allows them to alter their beliefs and reduce harm.
So, while someone may not be "wrong" for holding harmful beliefs shaped by their interpretations and upbringing, they are responsible for reflecting on these beliefs and, ideally, choosing interpretations that lead to less harm. Life, as a phenomenon, remains beyond labels, but our interpretations and actions within it are our responsibility.

Few people are "terrorists". That is people being in it for the terror... More often "terrorist" is a label applied to people by their victim, because terror is the overwhelming emotion that they connect with these people and their actions. So from the perspective of the outsider it fits, from the perspective of the individual in question, it likely doesn't.
So it's not really that people are drawn towards violence and terror as something that is good in and off itself, but rather that they were themselves subject to violence and terror and that this is presented to them as a valve, as a means to self-defense, to push back to prevent further violence and whatnot.
Often enough those claims are false, the narratives that people are told are faulty, incomplete and full of lies and half truths and it accomplishes nothing or makes things worse. But then again recruiting soldiers young might not just be for their physical fitness. So if they die before they realize how much they have been lied to and how little the real world resembles the world that they have been told to live in and which they thus actually felt living in. How much personal guilt could you actually attribute to them? And that's a question that is hard to answer because it relies on the subjective insights of that person. Like how much cognitive dissonance did they feel up to that point? How often did they feel "Wait that's not right" and pushed through it anyway with or without encouragement. If they never bothered with that question at all, they might even be "innocent" with respect to moral responsibility. Not sure if that's a state you would want to be in where you are blind to what's going on around you though.
Also outsiders might still attribute blame to you and mark you the root cause of their problems. So you might still be detained for their security reasons even though you yourself would not consider yourself to have done anything wrong.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The votes here tell a story which is a sad but realistic answer to the question

+1 Thanks for a good, if unpopular, answer.
